# How to upload an image in JS and see the preview of the file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to upload an image and that image has a preview. The problem is when I upload the image I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property ‘innerHTML’ of null
```

If I remove the following line:

```
imageContainer.innerHTML="";
```

this show in the screen:

```
1 console.log({numOfFiles}); Files Selected
```

and what I want is for images to appear, what am I doing wrong? I'm following a tutorial and in the tutorial it works for him and it doesn't for me

> HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <input type="file" name="fotosCarro" class="form-control" multiple="" id="file-input" onchange="preview()" accept="image/*" required="">
                <label for="file-input">Upload images</label>
                          <p id="num-of-files">No files chosen</p>
        <div class="images"></div>

</div>
```

> CSS

```
input[type="file"]{
    display:none;
}


.upload-label{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#025bee;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    width:300px;
    padding:18px 0;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}


#images{
    width:90%;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    gap:20px;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

figure{
 width:45%;
}


figcaption{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2.4vmin;
    margin-top:0.5vmin;
}
```

> JS

```
let fileInput=document.getElementById("file-input");
let imageContainer=document.getElementById("images");
let numOfFiles=document.getElementById("num-of-files");

function preview(){
    imageContainer.innerHTML="";
    console.log({imageContainer});
    numOfFiles.textContent=`${fileInput.files.length}
    console.log({numOfFiles});
    Files Selected`;

    for(i of fileInput.files){
        let reader=new FileReader();
        console.log({reader});
        let figure=document.createElement("figure");
        console.log({figure});
        let figCap=document.createElement("figcaption");
        console.log({figCap});
        figCap.innerText=i.name;
        figure.appendChild(figCap);
        reader.onload=()=>{
         let img=document.createElement("img");
         img.setAttribute("src",reader.result);
         figure.insertBefore(img,figCap);
        }
        imageContainer.appendChild(figure);
        reader.readAsDataURL(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means `imageContainer` is null, which means `document.getElementById("images");` doesn't find anything. The reason is that you have `<div class="images"></div>`, not `<div id="images"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the script tag for your javascript code after those elements you want to use or else the `document.getElementById(...)` won't find them

Also, the last div should have `id="images"` instead of class